# Adding fractions by overloading + operator using Class with Private Data Members

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading, private-members, fractions

First of all this is a Homework assignment. I just need some help 
   solving an issue related to the Fraction operator+() function. It is supposed to add together two fractions from an array in the function BinarayMathTest, but the Fraction::operator+() function only returns the denominator.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;



class Fraction
{
    private:
    int num,denom;
    public:

    Fraction operator + (const Fraction &right)const;

    friend ostream&operator<<(ostream&stream,Fraction obj);
    Fraction(int a=0,int b=1){num=a; denom=b;}

};

ostream&operator<<(ostream&stream,Fraction obj)
{
    stream<<obj.num<<'/';
   stream<<obj.denom;
   return stream;
}

Fraction Fraction::operator+(const Fraction &right)const
{
    Fraction temp;
    Fraction tempo;
    Fraction full;
    temp.num = ((num*right.denom) + (right.num*denom));
    tempo.denom =(denom*right.denom);
    full = (temp,tempo);
    return full;
}


void BinaryMathTest();


int main()
{

    BinaryMathTest();

    return 0;
}



void BinaryMathTest()
{
    cout << "\n----- Testing binary arithmetic between Fractions\n";

    const Fraction fr[] = {Fraction(1, 6), Fraction(1,3),
                       Fraction(-2,3), Fraction(5), Fraction(-4,3)};

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
          cout << fr[i] << " + " << fr[i+1] << " = " << fr[i] + fr[i+1]
<<endl;}}



/* OUTPUT
----- Testing binary arithmetic between Fractions
1/6 + 1/3 = 0/18
1/3 + -2/3 = 0/9
-2/3 + 5/1 = 0/3
5/1 + -4/3 = 0/3
*/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Fraction::operator+() function only returns the denominator.

Let's follow the lines of code in that function and see what happens.

```
Fraction temp;  // Creates an object with num = 0, denom = 1
Fraction tempo; //    ditto
Fraction full;  //    ditoo

temp.num = ((num*right.denom) + (right.num*denom)); // Sets the num of temp

tempo.denom =(denom*right.denom);  // Sets the denom of tempo
```

I have a feeling you don't know happens in the next line.

```
full = (temp,tempo);
```

The RHS of the line is a expression that uses the [comma operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54142/how-does-the-comma-operator-work).

It evaluates `temp` and discards the value. It evalutes `tempo` and assigns it to `full`. After that line, `full` has only the denominator since the numerator of `tempo` was never changed from `0`.

```
// Returns an object whose numerator is zero.
return full;
```

You can simplify that function to:

```
Fraction Fraction::operator+(const Fraction &right)const
{
   int num = ((num*right.denom) + (right.num*denom));
   int denom = (denom*right.denom);

   return Fraction(num, denom);
}
```

One thing to note in the above implementation is that it will quickly increase the values of `num` and `denom` if you keep adding `Fraction` objects. You can delay/prevent integer overflow, you'll have to reduce `num` and `denom` to smaller values by dividing both by their [GCD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor).

```
Fraction Fraction::operator+(const Fraction &right)const
{
   int num = ((num*right.denom) + (right.num*denom));
   int denom = (denom*right.denom);
   int gcd = get_gcd(num, denom);

   return Fraction(num/gcd, denom/gcd);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Fraction
{
    private:
    int num,denom;
    float full;
    public:

    Fraction operator + (const Fraction &right)const;

    friend ostream&operator<<(ostream&stream,Fraction obj);
    Fraction(int a=0,int b=1){num=a; denom=b;}

};

ostream&operator<<(ostream&stream,Fraction obj)
{
    stream<<obj.num<<'/';
   stream<<obj.denom;
   return stream;
}

Fraction Fraction::operator+(const Fraction &right)const
{
    Fraction temp;

    temp.num = ((num*right.denom) + (right.num*denom));
    temp.denom =(denom*right.denom);
    Fraction full(temp.num,temp.denom); /*objet of class cannot give call to constructor by using = unless it is overloaded*/

    return full;
}


void BinaryMathTest();


int main()
{

    BinaryMathTest();

    return 0;
}



void BinaryMathTest()
{
    cout << "\n----- Testing binary arithmetic between Fractions\n";

    const Fraction fr[] = {Fraction(1, 6), Fraction(1,3),
                       Fraction(-2,3), Fraction(5), Fraction(-4,3)};

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
          cout << fr[i] << " + " << fr[i+1] << " = " << fr[i] + fr[i+1]
<<endl;}}
```